# Where to place java packages like htmlparser?

Tags: java, html-parser

I am beginning to use java packages like HTMLParser, I have downloaded it and finding that there are many files and directories in it.

I wander, where to place them in my linux system? Is there a convention or a standard?

Comment: You mean 3rd party library? jsoup!

Comment: Depends on how you intend to use it, if you're developing application that should be portable, you should place it within application folder, also depends on if you want this library to be shared between users or not.

Comment: What should I do if I want to share that library between different users?

Comment: my assumption is that you're building desktop app. well, it depends on your target platform - win/lin/mac, basically if you want to share stuff between users, you might need some native package, or possibly go for some installer solution like: http://izpack.org

Comment: Just wondering; what would be the issue if you package these HTML parser libraries with your application. I mean, put them in same directory where your application will reside. Will there be any issue in doing that???

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty answer is "anywhere on the classpath", where the classpath is set either as a system property on the client machine (not recommended), as a temporary system property for the CLI session used to start the JVM (workable from a startup script), or as a commandline parameter to the JVM (usually the preferred choice).
First and second set the CLASSPATH environment variable, see the JDK or JRE documentation for the exact syntax and your operating system's and/or shell scripting documentation as well. Third uses the -cp commandline variable to the Java runtime and compiler, see their documentation for exact syntax.
Where to place the files on the filesystem? For development purposes I typically use a central folder on my computer containing all such libraries and link to that from my IDE or other development environment. For deployment/packaging to end users, it is traditional to have a "lib" subfolder to the product folder that contains all distributable content, and put the jar files in that.

Answer (score -1):

Java packages come in two forms. **Source code** - all the files and directories you mention - and packaged as **jars**. A common convention in Java projects is that the project has a lib directory that contains all the jars that the project depends on. These projects often use a shell script which adds all the jars to the Java classpath prior to executing the project code.

However many projects are switching from this method of dealing with dependencies to using a build tool like [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) which automatically handles dependency management. Other alternatives include [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) or [Gradle](http://gradle.org/why/robust-dependency-management/). For an introduction see the [5 minute introduction to Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) or the [Maven 3 tutorial](http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2011/06/maven-3-tutorial-project-setup/).

Here you write a pom.xml (project object model file) which specifies which libraries (jars) your project uses. Maven then stores all the jars for your different projects in a .m2 directory in your local directory, keeping track of where it obtained them, and their versioning information.

This makes developing much easier as you do not need to create the lib directory or manually manage dependencies. You also avoid a lot of the complexities of setting the classpath, as Maven automatically does this for you during common lifecyle stages such as compilation and test. Recent versions of Eclipse can read the Maven pom and automatically configure your classpath from it.

Once you have built the project, Maven can also help create "**fat jars**" that contain all the jars your project depends on, via the assembly plugin or the Shade plugin. This makes distributing the code easier when you are [building an executable](http://devdanke.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/creating-an-executable-jar-with-maven-2/) that you want someone to use. If you are distributing a jar, then your pom.xml describes the dependencies of your project, avoiding the need to distribute the jars it depends on.

For laying out files in general on a Linux system consult the [Linux Filesystem hierarchy standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: that doesn't answer the question, it merely offers a workaround to hide the real issue (a decent one, but he should know the system and be able to use it without tooling eventually).